# Compare JSON result to String

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to get a JSON result from a url and check if it is equal to "OK" so I can preform a segue. I'm currently getting the error:
`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'String'`.

Here is my code:

```
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("LightningDB Error")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let responseData = jsonData as? NSDictionary {
                        if let response = responseData["response"] {
                            if response == "OK" {
                                performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: responseString)
                            } else {
                                warnField.text = "This user does not exist."
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Thanks!

P.S. doing `print(response)` is just fine.

Comment: First of all don't use NSDictionary, use native Swift struct - Array.
You also need to cast response to String if you want to compare it to a String by `if let response = responseData["response"] as? String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler must know the (expected) type of `response`

```
if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [String:Any] {
    if let response = jsonData["response"] as? String { ...
```

As always:

- Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift
- Never use `.mutableContainers` in Swift, it's meaningless.

Comment: Ok, testing this out now :)

Comment: This works, but when I try to perform a segue, it tells me to change the line from `performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: response)` to `                                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: response)`, doing so crashes the app when run. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does a segue with identifier `loginSegue` exist? What error message to do get?